# Visual Studio C# ChromiumWebBrowser Constantly Refreshes the Design Screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chromium

I am making a windows form C# project via Visual Studio program. I am using ChromiumWebBrowser from Chefsharp in this project. But I have a problem and I can't solve it. Whenever I make a change anywhere in the code, regardless of the code, the screen refreshes when I switch to the design screen. This situation is very annoying. It takes 6-7 seconds to refresh the screen. I constantly write code in the code field and return to the design screen, wasting time. I hope I was able to explain my problem. Even if I put a space in the code field of the project and delete it back, when I switch to the form design screen, the screen is completely refreshed and I wait. How can I solve this problem?

When I delete WebBrowser, the problem goes away. But I need to solve this problem.

Video:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CwcESMCHITslE3J4ueghifpK1E_OcN0t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues)